# How to use the same adapter for two different type of objects?

Tags: android, object, custom-adapter

I have two adapters with same layout and everything except the parameter passed in constructer is different so for this i have to make two different adapter everything same but only constructer different.

```
public MoviePackageGridAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                               ArrayList<MoviePackage> packageList) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.packageList = packageList;
}
```

and the other is :

```
public PackageGridAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                          ArrayList<ChannelPackage> packageList) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.packageList = packageList;
}
```

everything is same inside in adapter expect the objects. I want to use the same adapter for two different types of object. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have two `constructors` taking the same parameters. But you can add a flag to the second one, indicating which you object you passed, like:

```
boolean isChannelPackage;

public MoviePackageGridAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                           ArrayList<MoviePackage> packageList) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.packageList = packageList;
    this.isChannelPackage = false;
}


public PackageGridAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                      ArrayList<ChannelPackage> packageList, boolean isChannelPackage) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.packageList = packageList;
    this.isChannelPackage = isChannelPackage;
}
```

You can use the flag `isChannelPackage` to indicate which data type you receive.

Comment: I cannot put two constructors with two different name in the adapter class. I want to use one constructor with can be used for two different object types

Comment: I think removing the `<...>` from your constructors and variables should work  -  but I do not recommend it, since you have unchecked calls and with further work on your classes, this can end up in a mess. Above method is recommended, because you always know which `objects` your `ArrayList` contains. For custom methods in your classes, you would need casting, which can lead to errors, which you need to catch.... etc. :)